# Вывод имен нескольких таблиц из базы данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, база-данных

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть 7 таблиц, 4 из них содержат столбец 'price'.

**Надо сделать следующее:**

Мне нужно вынуть из базы данных названия только тех таблиц, которые содержат столбец 'price'. А затем вывести их через запятую и присвоить переменной результат.

**Делаю вот так:**

```
$basessites = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='sale' AND COLUMN_NAME='price'");
if (mysql_num_rows($basessites) > 0)
{$bsites = mysql_fetch_assoc($basessites);
$sites = implode(",", $bsites);
echo $sites;
}
```

Выводит только одну таблицу из 4-х соответствующих условию. Как быть, подскажите, что делаю не так!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте цикл:

```
while($bsites = mysql_fetch_assoc($basessites)){
    $sites = implode(",", $bsites);
    echo $sites;
}
```

Comment: Отлично работает только выводит только 3 а не 4 названия, первое не выводит!

Comment: попробуйте запустить sql запрос в phpmyadmin.

Comment: в phpmyadmin все выводит

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой выход нашел, [[@terantul](/users/11594/terantul)](/users/11594/terantul) Спасибо за выход на мысль!

```
$basessites = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='sale' AND COLUMN_NAME='price'");
if (mysql_num_rows($basessites) > 0)
{$bsites = mysql_fetch_assoc($basessites);}
do {$sites.=$bsites['TABLE_NAME'].", "; }
while($bsites = mysql_fetch_assoc($basessites));
echo $sites;
```